# Traveling without EU Visa (from Netherlands to Spain) with US Refugee travel document

Tags: schengen-visas

I was planning to visit my family in Tenerife.
All appointments in Spain consulate SF are booked until the end of February. 
As a green card holder (ex-asylee) I have only a Refugee travel document. I can travel with this document to some EU countries without a visa (Netherlands one of them). I know that for domestic flights inside EU customs don't check the visa. 
Do you think how likely I might get into the problem if I'll fly from Holland to Tenerife without Schengen Visa? What will be the circumstances?

According to this document I don't need a visa:
https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=bda8422e-9057-47c3-973f-360c5e95fa29

Comment: Having recently done a 'within Schengen' flight, I have to tell you that both directions my ID card or passport was asked for. Airline staff still have responsibilities to not bring people who do not have the right visa.

Comment: The link you show applies to travelers with 1951 Convention refugee travel documents. The US refugee travel document is not such a document, as the US did not ratify the 1951 Convention. Therefore it does not apply to you.

Comment: That said, I think the airline will deny you boarding as their system will state that you require a visa to visit Spain. As noted in the linked post above, you might be able to travel to such countries via ground, if you avoid any irregular immigration checks, but it's not really practical to go to Tenerife that way.

Comment: The risk that you run in trouble is moderately high and I wouldn't recommend trying but note that it is indeed possible to fly without showing ID (I did it most recently on Amsterdam-Stuttgart a couple of year ago). ID is checked very frequently, but not to enforce immigration law. It also serves other purposes including safeguarding airlines price discrimination tactics (being able to resell tickets would deprive them from important revenue). But it's likely that a somewhat unusual document might invite additional scrutiny.